# How to prohibit generating row number in python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big pandas dataframe with many rows.

```
    id1   id2  id3  count
0   a     b    a    1
1   a     b    b    2
2   a     b    c    3
```

I want to calculate row occurences. Here is how I am trying to do this.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

pdf = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data_tupl)
cnts = Counter(pdf.itertuples())
```

Unfortunately `itertuples()` outputs a row number `(0, 'a', 'b', 'a', 1)` which I absolutely don't need. I can of course slice it off but that will require an intermediate step which will slow down the performance. Is it possible to inhibit pandas row output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting index=False? `pdf.itertuples(index=False)`

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html

Answer (score 2):

For large DataFrames with lots of repeats, it may be faster to use Pandas methods to `groupby/count` the rows than it would be to use `collections.Counter`:

```
In [75]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, size=(10000,4)))

In [76]: df.reset_index().groupby(list(df.columns)).count().to_dict('dict')['index']
Out[76]: 
{(0, 0, 0, 0): 639,
 (0, 0, 0, 1): 621,
 (0, 0, 1, 0): 658,
 (0, 0, 1, 1): 595,
 (0, 1, 0, 0): 601,
 (0, 1, 0, 1): 640,
 (0, 1, 1, 0): 643,
 (0, 1, 1, 1): 632,
 (1, 0, 0, 0): 637,
 (1, 0, 0, 1): 644,
 (1, 0, 1, 0): 574,
 (1, 0, 1, 1): 642,
 (1, 1, 0, 0): 612,
 (1, 1, 0, 1): 667,
 (1, 1, 1, 0): 588,
 (1, 1, 1, 1): 607}

In [77]: collections.Counter(df.itertuples(index=False))
Out[77]: Counter({Pandas(_0=1, _1=1, _2=0, _3=1): 667, Pandas(_0=0, _1=0, _2=1, _3=0): 658, Pandas(_0=1, _1=0, _2=0, _3=1): 644, Pandas(_0=0, _1=1, _2=1, _3=0): 643, Pandas(_0=1, _1=0, _2=1, _3=1): 642, Pandas(_0=0, _1=1, _2=0, _3=1): 640, Pandas(_0=0, _1=0, _2=0, _3=0): 639, Pandas(_0=1, _1=0, _2=0, _3=0): 637, Pandas(_0=0, _1=1, _2=1, _3=1): 632, Pandas(_0=0, _1=0, _2=0, _3=1): 621, Pandas(_0=1, _1=1, _2=0, _3=0): 612, Pandas(_0=1, _1=1, _2=1, _3=1): 607, Pandas(_0=0, _1=1, _2=0, _3=0): 601, Pandas(_0=0, _1=0, _2=1, _3=1): 595, Pandas(_0=1, _1=1, _2=1, _3=0): 588, Pandas(_0=1, _1=0, _2=1, _3=0): 574})

In [78]: %timeit collections.Counter(df.itertuples(index=False))
100 loops, best of 3: 12.8 ms per loop

In [79]: %timeit df.reset_index().groupby(list(df.columns)).count().to_dict('dict')['index']
100 loops, best of 3: 3.74 ms per loop
```

For a DataFrame with few repeats, the speed is comparable:

```
In [80]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000, size=(10000,4)))

In [81]: %timeit collections.Counter(df.itertuples(index=False))
100 loops, best of 3: 11.2 ms per loop

In [82]: %timeit df.reset_index().groupby(list(df.columns)).count().to_dict('dict')['index']
100 loops, best of 3: 11.7 ms per loop
```